# json.success no me funciona o no entra en el codigo

Tags: php, jquery

Buenas alguien podría decirme por que no entra a mi condición if solo es una validación para checar si existe el vin del carro si es no nomas muestra mensaje y si es si me inserta es en MVC, me marca error en el código solo en el controlador marca que se encontró el auto correctamente y como q al mismo tiempo entra al else del if de parámetros incompletos, estube imprimiendo cada cosa pero no encontré nada

mi js

```
$('.prueba_manejo_tabla').click(function(){
            var id = $('#contacto_prueba_manejo').val();         
            var persona = $('#persona_prueba_manejo').val();
            var fecha = $('#fecha_prueba_manejo').val();
            var ciudad = $('#ciudad').val();
            var inv = $('#idinventario').val();

            if(inv !='' && fecha !='' && persona !=''){
                $.ajax({
                   url: base_url + "buscar/buscar_auto",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data : {contacto : id, inv : inv, persona : persona, fecha : fecha},
                    success: function(json, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        console.log(json);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(inv);
                        if (json.success) {
                            swal('Bien', 'SE ENCONTRO VIN', 'success');
                            $.getJSON(base_url+'contacto/registrar_prueba_manejo_inventario', {contacto : id, inv : inv, persona : persona, fecha : fecha}, function(data)
                            {
                               swal({
                            title: json.titulo,
                            text: json.mensaje,
                            type: json.status,
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            confirmButtonText: 'ok',
                        }).then(function(){
                            $('#modal_prueba_manejo').modal('hide');
                            $('#contacto_prueba_manejo').val('');
                            $('#idcontacto').val('');
                            $('#idinventario').val('');
                            $('#persona_prueba_manejo').val('');
                            if (ciudad == 'Tijuana')
                            var newWindow = window.open("");
                        }); 

                            });
                        }else{
                            swal('Error!', 'NO SE ENCONTRO VIN', 'error');

                        }
                        },
                        complete: function(textStatus, jqXHR){
                    },
                    error: function(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR){
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                    }

                });
            }else{
                swal('Error!', 'Favor de llenar todos los campos', 'error');
            }
        });
```

CONTROLADOR

```
$respuesta = array ();
        if(isset($_POST['inv']))
        {
            $prueba_manejo = $this->Contactomodel->buscar_auto();
            print_r($prueba_manejo);
            if($prueba_manejo)
            {
                $respuesta['status'] = true;
                $respuesta['titulo'] = 'Listo!';
                $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Auto encontrado';

            }
            else
            {
                $respuesta['status'] = false;
                $respuesta['titulo'] = 'Error!';
                $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Error al registrar prueba';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $respuesta['status'] = 'error';
            $respuesta['titulo'] = 'Error!';
            $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Parametros incompletos prueba';

        }
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow.

Hay varias cosas:

1. Lo único que debes poner en el parámetro del `success` es el valor que esperas del servidor. Ponlo así:

   ```
   success: function(json){

   ...
   ```
2. Con respecto al `if`, si observas en tu código PHP, el objeto que devuelves no tiene una clave `success`, deberías verificar la clave `status`, que es la que eventualmente existiría en el json:

   ```
   if (json.status) {

   ...
   ```
3. Para asegurar que no habrá problemas de codificación, se recomienda poner un `header` antes de imprimir el resultado.

   ```
   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode($respuesta);
   ```

Con esos cambios debería funcionar como esperas.

Comment: gracias me ayudo, tambien quite el isset por que no dejaba pasar, lo borre y funciono